# How can I change the internal groovy version from gradle 6?

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy

[In the screenshot are marked the two groovy versions I need to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k1hI.png)
Im working on a grails 4 project trying to integrate it with open clover plugin for testing coverage.
Im trying to use the groovy version I have installed and set as default in my local, instead of using the internal version that ships with gradle.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't replace or remove the shipped/provided Groovy that comes with Gradle because:

- Gradle’s build language is based on Groovy
- Parts of Gradle are implemented in Groovy

So Gradle is effectively tied to whatever version of Groovy it was shipped with for that release. If your project requires a different version or requires Groovy in general, then you need to explicitly declare a Groovy dependency as you would for any Groovy project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: my answer is hard and not adviced.

If really you want to change the version of groovy in gradle, you might clone gradle from source, edit `subproject/language-java/build.gradle.kts` for java compiler, and same in any subprojects.

I do not recommend you to do that.